# Is there a way to compute product correlation with refreshing order IDs in tableau or Excel?

Tags: excel, correlation, tableau-desktop

I have issues with cleaning my data. 1 year of sales data provided —> sales data only provided quantity sold.

- order id refreshes every day. Starts from 1
- some orders may purchase just one item, but some have more than one item

[image: Example of sales data]

The example illustrates the number of items sold on 2nd Jan 2020 and there are a total of 168 orders for that day. When 3 Jan 2020 starts, the order id is refreshed back to 1.

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused as to what your problem is exactly.  Can you elaborate or provide an example of what you want to see?

Comment: I would like to create a correlation matrix between various products. What is the correlation coefficient between espresso and non-cream cakes and so on. It would be easier for me to do so if my order IDs run consecutively from day 1 to day 365. However, the order ID resets back to 01 every new business day.

Comment: Ok, so you're issue is that the order ID restarts each day, got it.  Do they need to be consecutive or just in a format that will put them in order?  Does that make sense?  So what if it was 2168 and the next day was 3001?  Weird question but there's a reason why I ask.

Comment: Another question, why can't you just create a new column and have a sequential number starting from the top down to the last row?

Comment: I think it would be best if they’re in consecutive numbers. Some order IDs may have 1 product, some may have more than 1 product purchased. At the end of the year, I would know how many sales orders do I have based on the order ID for the last day of the year.

Comment: I don’t think I can have a sequential number in a new column. This is because each order is unique and some customers may purchase more than 1 product.

Comment: From what you're saying, you simply want a unique order ID, is that right?  I don't see why they need to be 100% sequential, that makes no sense to me.  If you want to retain the original order ID, just use a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a unique order ID then something like combining the date and order ID will do it for you, it just needs to be placed into a new column ...

```
=TEXT(D2,"yyyyMMdd") & TEXT(B2,"00000")
```

[image: Formula]

This will, you retain your original data but have the unique order ID to filter on if need be.

Comment: I think I might still have an issue :0. In the picture I have attached, some order IDs have more than 1 type of products purchased. E.g Order ID 2 for 3rd Jan.

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: I think I got it. Let me try it out and see! Thank you 